# Cannot create database scoped credential with a login that is part of an AD group

Tags: sql-server, database-permissions

I'm trying to find the minimum required permission or role that would allow a user that was assigned permissiosn through an AD group in Azure SQL server to create a database scoped credential via the following syntax.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [SomeCredential] 
    WITH IDENTITY = N'someSqlUser', SECRET='someSqlPassword';
```

Based on documentation, the following permissions are needed.

```
GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::[MyDatabase] TO [SqlAdminGroup]
```

The error when someone from that group tries to create a database scoped credential is below:

```
The specified schema name "personInSqlAdminGroup@mytentant.com" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
```

So what is interesting is that when I try this with a individual SQL login where I specifically gave the login CONTROL permission, it works.  When I try this via granting to an AD group is when I get the specified schema name error.  I added the group with a default schema of DBO.

I believe there is an issue with an AD group in SQL not having a default schema, so any object creation would need to fully qualify the object with [dbo].[object]. However, database scoped credentials don't seem to want a schema because specified it results in a parsing error.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [dbo].[SomeCredential] 
    WITH IDENTITY = N'someSqlUser', SECRET='someSqlPassword';
```

So if it doesn't want a schema, why does it complain about the specified schema name of the user not existing?

Comment: SQL Server has help pages for each statement. Each help page lists the [permissions required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions).

Comment: I've already tried that, but I did update the question based on this comment.

Comment: So what is interesting is that I tried this with a single login and it does work as documentation suggests.  When I try this by granting to an AD group is when I get the specified schema name error.  I added the group with a default schema of DBO.

Comment: I'm starting to think it has more to do with assigning these permissions to an AD group.

Comment: Are database scoped credentials set up for the database? SQL standard is not to allow them. Like NOT AT ALL. Did you enable contained databases? Did you set up a master key as per documentation?

Comment: This is an Azure SQL Server.  They are required to use EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE

Comment: as per documentation: Permissions: Requires CONTROL permission on the database.

Comment: Yes, but when assigning that to an AD group, it does not work.

Comment: CREATE an AD group, add to database, and then assign CONTROL permission to that group as documented.  Then try to login with a user within that group and attempt to create a DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL.  You should get the same error.  If you do the exact same steps with an individual SQL or AD account, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented issue here [Use Azure Active Directory authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview). Quoting the relevant bullet from "Azure AD features and limitations": -

> Azure AD users that are part of a group that has db_owner server role cannot use the CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL syntax against Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse. You will see the following error:
>
> SQL Error [2760] [S0001]: The specified schema name 'user@mydomain.com' either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
>
> Grant the db_owner role directly to the individual Azure AD user to mitigate the CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL issue.

The db_owner role membership does not match your CONTROL on database scenario exactly, but it looks likely to be the same underlying issue. I don't have an explanation for this surfacing as the schema error.